# how to create running skew (constant updating skew of increasing set of numbers from a start date) pine script - stock trading

Tags: pine-script, distribution, cumulative-sum, pine-script-v5, skew

I recently had help creating a running ave/mean of ROC from a start date on a stock price chart. Thank you mr_statler for creating a working code. I would now like to do the same thing by creating  running skew. I can't seem to translate the code from mean to skew. I will post the code mr_statler  wrote for running mean.

here is mr_statler's running ave/mean code"

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

var roc_array = array.new_float(0)
float avg_roc_array = array.avg(roc_array)

start = input.time(timestamp("04 Oct 2022 00:00:00"), "Start date")

if time >= start
    roc = ((close / close[1]) - 1) * 100
    array.push(roc_array, roc)
    avg_roc_array := array.avg(roc_array)

plot(avg_roc_array)
```

now here is the code I am trying to create for running skew:

```
//@version=5
indicator("running skew")
//roc
length = input.int(1, minval=1)
source = input(close, "Source")
roc = 100 * (source - source[length])/source[length]
plot(roc, color=#2962FF, title="ROC")
hline(0, color=#787B86, title="Zero Line")
//skew
skewness(roc, length) =>
    avg = ta.sma(roc, length)
    stdv = ta.stdev(roc, length)
    sum = math.pow(roc - avg, 3)
    for i = 1 to length - 1
        sum := sum + math.pow(roc[i] - avg, 3)
    ((sum / length) / math.pow(stdv, 3))

skew = skewness(roc, length)

//initializiation
var roc_array = array.new_float(0)
float skew_roc_array = skew

start = input.time(timestamp("04 Oct 2022 00:00:00"), "Start date")


//running skew
if time >= start
    skew = skewness(roc, length)
    array.push(skew_array, skew)
     skew_roc_array := (roc_array)

plot(skew_roc_array, title="skew", color=color.yellow)
```

updated code 7-6-23

```
//@version=5
indicator("running skew of roc")
//roc
roclength = input.int(1, minval=1)
length = input.int(2, minval=1)
source = input(close, "Source")
roc = 100 * (source - source[roclength])/source[roclength]
// plot(roc, color=#2962FF, title="ROC")
// hline(0, color=#787B86, title="Zero Line")
//skew
skewness(roc, length) =>
    avg = ta.sma(roc, length)
    stdv = ta.stdev(roc, length)
    sum = math.pow(roc - avg, 3)
    for i = 1 to length - 1
        sum := sum + math.pow(roc[i] - avg, 3)
    ((sum / length) / math.pow(stdv, 3))

_skew = skewness(roc, length)

start = input.time(timestamp("13 Oct 2022 09:30:00"), "Start date")

skew = time >= start ? _skew : na

plot(skew, title="skew", color=color.yellow)
```

Answer (score 0):

`ta.stdev(roc, length)` will return `0` if `length` is equal to `1`, and that causes that `((sum / length) / math.pow(stdv, 3))` is basically dividing by zero and return `na`. You first need to fix this.

After that, if you just want to plot `skew` on from a specific date onwards, you can use the following code:

```
//@version=5
indicator("running skew")
//roc
length = input.int(2, minval=1)
source = input(close, "Source")
roc = 100 * (source - source[length])/source[length]
// plot(roc, color=#2962FF, title="ROC")
// hline(0, color=#787B86, title="Zero Line")
//skew
skewness(roc, length) =>
    avg = ta.sma(roc, length)
    stdv = ta.stdev(roc, length)
    sum = math.pow(roc - avg, 3)
    for i = 1 to length - 1
        sum := sum + math.pow(roc[i] - avg, 3)
    ((sum / length) / math.pow(stdv, 3))

_skew = skewness(roc, length)

start = input.time(timestamp("04 Oct 2022 00:00:00"), "Start date")

skew = time >= start ? _skew : na

plot(skew, title="skew", color=color.yellow)
```

Comment: thank you mr_statler. I have updated my code for running skewness. unfortunately, the skewness readout on tradingview reads 0.0000 constantly. I have tried both regular and logarithmic chart scaling. I put the updated code into the original post labeled 7-6-23